# How to create Appserver, schema, trigger and modules DB in every host attached to a cluster?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, ml-gradle

I am trying to configure MarkLogic instance setup in AWS. I have a cluster with 3 nodes(3 EC2 instances) attached to ELB. I want each of the host to have the same App Server, Modules , Schema and Trigger DB. How can i set it up using ml-gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Try walking through the [Getting Started](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Getting-started) guide first. When you create an app server, it will by default exist on each host. And your database will by default have one or more forests on each host. The fact that it's AWS doesn't impact anything here. Also see this [sample project](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/sample-project) for an example of an application with a schemas and triggers database (along with many other kinds of resources).